# How can I trigger a toast inside a click event when state of another variable is changed?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

At First Button1 should be pressed. After that Button2 is pressed to denote that the loading task is completed. Now I want the toast message in console when Button2 is pressed after Button1.

````
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const handleClick1 = () => {
    if (isLoading === false) {
      console.log("Show Toast Message");
    }
  }
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }
  return (
    <div >
      <button onClick={handleClick1}>Button 1 (create account button)</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick2}>Button 2 (to define account creating complete)</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is a little confusing but check this out.
You need to click btn2 to set loading false and activate btn1. After btn1 is clicked you will get a message if btn2 is clicked afterwards.

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isBtn1Pressed,setIsBtn1Pressed] = useState(false);
  const handleClick1 = () => {
    if (isLoading === false) {
      console.log("Show Toast Message");
      setIsBtn1Pressed(true);
    }
  }
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    if(isBtn1Pressed){
      console.log("Show Toast Messeage for BTN2 after BTN1");
    }
  }
  return (
    <div >
      <button onClick={handleClick1}>Button 1 (create account button)</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick2}>Button 2 (to define account creating complete)</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: which button I need to press first, in your code?